# set number for start of counting

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to set a number for starting the counting of the same data in the row

```
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "chrom   position    strand  value   label
chr1       17432    -           0   romeo
chr1       17433    -           0   romeo
chr1       17434    -           0   romeo
chr1       17435    -           0   romeo
chr1       17409    -           1   juliet
chr1       17410    -           1   juliet
chr1       17411    -           1   juliet")

#set the starting count number for romeo
number = 2

#set the starting count number for romeo
juliet= 3

#install.packages('dplyr')
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    group_by(label) %>%
    mutate(number = 1:n())

dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "chrom   position    strand  value   label
chr1       17432    -           0   romeo
chr1       17433    -           0   romeo
chr1       17434    -           0   romeo
chr1       17435    -           0   romeo
chr1       17409    -           1   juliet
chr1       17410    -           1   juliet
chr1       17411    -           1   juliet")


#install.packages('dplyr')
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    group_by(label) %>%
    mutate(number = 1:n())

chrom position       value      label         number
chr1    17432   -   0          romeo             2
chr1    17433   -   0          romeo             3
chr1    17434   -   0          romeo             4
chr1    17435   -   0          romeo             5
chr1    17409   -   1          juliet            3
chr1    17410   -   1          juliet            4
chr1    17411   -   1          juliet            5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a dataframe with `label` and their starting value so that it is scalable and can accomodate as many `labels` as we want.

```
lkup <- data.frame(label = c("romeo", "juliet"), number = c(2, 3))
```

We can then join the two dataframe, get the starting value and add it to current row number to get new `number`

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
   left_join(lkup, by = "label")  %>%
   group_by(label) %>%
   mutate(number = row_number() + number - 1)
   #Or same as OP's attempt
   #mutate(number = 1:n() + number - 1)

#  chrom position strand value label  number
#  <fct>    <int> <fct>  <int> <fct>   <dbl>
#1 chr1     17432 -          0 romeo       2
#2 chr1     17433 -          0 romeo       3
#3 chr1     17434 -          0 romeo       4
#4 chr1     17435 -          0 romeo       5
#5 chr1     17409 -          1 juliet      3
#6 chr1     17410 -          1 juliet      4
#7 chr1     17411 -          1 juliet      5
```

---

In base R, we can use `merge` with `ave` using the same logic

```
dat$number <- with(merge(dat, lkup, by = "label", all.x = TRUE), 
              number + ave(number, label, FUN = seq_along) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `data.table` using a join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[data.table(label = c('romeo', 'juliet'), number = 2:3), 
      number := seq_len(.N) + number - 1, on = .(label), by = .EACHI]
dat
#   chrom position strand value  label number
#1:  chr1    17432      -     0  romeo      2
#2:  chr1    17433      -     0  romeo      3
#3:  chr1    17434      -     0  romeo      4
#4:  chr1    17435      -     0  romeo      5
#5:  chr1    17409      -     1 juliet      3
#6:  chr1    17410      -     1 juliet      4
#7:  chr1    17411      -     1 juliet      5
```

Comment: sir I used this following code hrdata <- hrfile
hrdata <- hrdata %>%
  group_by(SOURCE) %>%
  mutate(ticker = cumsum(number)) how can set a number for the beginning of counting of cumsum?

Comment: @KikoRosario I didn't get your comment correctly.  But, this works on the example you provided